# Can MySQL server load data from a C# application?

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, database-connection

I'm using a local MySQL-server(MySQL Workbench 6.3) on my PC and send data from a C# application using the .NET connector. It works fine, so I'm able to insert data (i.e. rows) to the server or delete them.

Is it possible for the server to load data from my C# application and insert it into the database? I would use trigger events in the database and load new data from the C# application regularly.

If there is a possibility, I would like to test the speed of both methods. Does anyone have the answer?

Comment: Well, in this case your C# application should somehow handle handler network requests and response to it so it fact it becomes "server" and mysql server becomes "client" who are sending requests and receiving responses. While it is generally possible - it it not straightforward to implement, and in fact it is too broad question to be discussed in StackOverflow Q&A format.

Comment: Please remember to come back and up-vote + accept an answer if you find it useful. It helps you, those trying to answer your questions, and the community at large.

Comment: I would be happy to show you a concrete way to increase your throughput by 10x if you post the full code of the way you are doing it now.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question, the answer is no. The database server will not "connect" to your application to, from its perspective, "load"/"download" data. Your application has to insert the data using valid SQL queries. If you want to schedule something, you'll need to have the schedule in your application (e.g. a recurring timer) or at the OS level (e.g. Windows service or Linux cronjob) so that a program takes care of it.

However, if you're trying to move data from one database to another (e.g. migration), then you can dump the schema into a file and then ask the other database to "restore" from this data dump, just as if you were restoring from some kind of backup. **NOTE:** *If you do this, you're replacing, not updating, existing data.*

Note that the dump basically contains SQL statements that the other DB would execute in order to create the tables, constraints, data rows, etc.

Comment: ok thanks. So I have to use another file to buffer the data anyway?

Comment: It depends. If you create a data dump, then it will be placed into a file. If you have the application moving data around, then it can simply `select` data from some connection to `Database-A` and then `insert` it to some `Database-B` using a second connection, avoiding the need for writing files on disk.

Comment: There's a trade-off. An application can avoid the overhead of you having to manually use MySQL commands (e.g. `mysqldump`, etc), transfer the file between servers, and then launch the restore operation, so it might be "faster" in this sense. OTOH, restoring from a dump might be faster as the data is now local to the server and does not need to be transferred over the network in chunks every time, so it might be faster once started. There're lots of factors here, including network, HDD speeds, etc. You should start with which ever is *easier* for you first, and *then* decide if more is needed.